# Changing the order of sections in App Store Listing?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

When someone comes to my app's page on Apple's App Store, right now they see the sections in this order:

- Version Information/What's New Section
- Description Section

Is there a way to swap the two sections? I want visitors to my app store page **to immediately see the Description of my app, followed by the What's New section, not vice versa.**

This might be a very basic question but I could not find any helpful articles online and appreciate the help!

Comment: No, you can't change the order. If a user already has downloaded your app, they will see the What's New section at the top. Otherwise, the app screenshots are at the top, followed by the description.

Answer (score 0):

The (Mac) App Store layout is determined and managed by Apple. There is no way for you to change any of the order of the elements.